# detect connection problem in NSUrlConnection

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a class that implements the delegate `NSUrlConnection`, from connection   `didFailWithError`. How can I detect an error caused when there is no Internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

According to my memory, the error code of the missing Internet connection is -1009.
In method

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

try checking `[error code]`